# CSS background-image getting cut off

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <form id="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Ваше имя</label><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="..." />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="comment">Ссылка на VK</label><input type="text" name="comment" placeholder="или другое (для связи)" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="file" name="file" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Нажми, чтобы загрузить фото" onclick="submit()" />
  </form>
  <div id="output"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html { 
  background: url("https://pp.vk.me/c628218/v628218217/d86f/Y2PKptBEnS0.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

[google script demo](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwj7pG7cMoYUanrC31ktOOlNRBZFnrnFBQqEtecFTqmzN7g9iHD/exec)

Why is the background picture cut off (only the height of the `<div id="app">`)?

Comment: Without the script the picture is displayed correctly for the entire browser window when tested in Chrome -> devtools (F12) -> edit html -> paste your code.

Comment: You have left out an import piece of the puzzle, your page is using a template system or similar. I see `<caja>` tags in your markup.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the following CSS

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

**[JSfiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/hLd3828x/)**

Comment: Will this cause an issue if he adds content that would expand past a "single page"? Would he be better off adding a dummy div with a large height style attribute? EDIT: nevermind, I didn't see the "fixed" attribute, he obviously wants a single background page.

Comment: This will not fix the issue as the background image is not being applied to the html or body tag. User is using a template system. jsFiddle doesn't accurately replicate the OPs development environment.

Comment: now I have a white band at the top of the page.

<style>
html, body {
    height: 100%; 
 background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-image: url("https://pp.vk.me/c628218/v628218217/d86f/Y2PKptBEnS0.jpg");
    }
#app{
  margin: 55px auto;
  width: 350px;
}
<!-- rewrite add-ons.css -->
input {
  width: 100%;
}
.form-group{
  margin: 9px 0px 9px 0px;
}
</style>

Comment: The white band is a product of the `<caja>` tags (since the issue does not manifest itself in the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/hLd3828x/)). I cannot offer additional guidance as I have no idea what generated these tags or where they are for.

Comment: It looks proper if you add the original line of CSS that I suggested above instead of your versions where `height: 100%` is only applied to the `html` element: `html, body { height: 100%; }`  ::  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/hLd3828x/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code

```
html, body { height: 100%;background: url("https://pp.vk.me/c628218/v628218217/d86f/Y2PKptBEnS0.jpg");}
```

Dont give no repeat.

Comment: The `background` does not need to be applied to both `HTML` and `body`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using some sort of template system and that is getting in the way. Your form markup is being wrapped with `<caja>` tags. Currently your `html` selector style is being applied to a `<caja-v-html>` tag. Looks like styles are being parsed and applied to `<caja>` elements instead of regular HTML elements.

The `<caja-v-html>` element is behaving like a DIV and will only be as tall as it's content without a height specified.